# How to handle integers too large for uint64_t in a synchronous Dart native extension?

Tags: c++, c, dart, dart-native-extension

When the user passes a number larger than `2^64 - 1` to a native function then the integer can't fit into a `unit64_t`.

What is the simplest way to write a synchronous native extension that can handle integers of arbitrarily large size?  Since it appears we must use the Dart_Embedding API to retrieve values from a Dart_NativeArguments instance, how do we retrieve these values without loss of precision?

Comment: "handle values of this size" is unclear.  All you have said is that the number is larger than "2^64 - 1".  You have not specified an upper bound - or it it boundless?  If you only need 65-bit precision [long double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double) may work for you.

Comment: @chux Thanks for catching that, I've updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Blasphemous suggestion: pass it as a string ? ;-)

Or [de]mangle it into/out of byte array ?